# Elesticsearch and Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, elasticsearch

I'm trying to wire EmberJS with ElasticSearch. So far, I've read most of the Ember documentation, and found out [this adapter](https://github.com/karmi/ember-data-elasticsearch) for ElasticSearch.

The problem is I can't figure out how to use it (i.e. configure it so that when I call `store.save()`, my model is sent to ES.

What I have ATM is a newly created project with Ember generator (ember new ), and a generated controller, router, model, etc. My problem is that the Ember document explains how to [customise adapters](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/customizing-adapters/), but not how to use them (or I missed that part). The ES adapter's documentation says :

```
var App = Em.Application.create();

App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 4,
  adapter: DS.ElasticSearchAdapter.create({url: 'http://localhost:9200'})
});
```

which implies to create a Store, whereas I can only see ways to extend it in the Ember documentation. Furthermore, I already have a Store in my application.

So the questions are:

- do I need to override the store creation to replace it with the ES one (and where to do that) OR
- do I need to extend the existing one, and in this case, how should I do that ?

Also, when it says:

> First, load the ember-data/lib/adapters/elasticsearch_adapter.js file
>   in your application.

where and how that should be done ?

Answer (score 0):

On your first questions/s

> do I need to override the store creation to replace it with the ES one
>   (and where to do that) OR do I need to extend the existing one, and in
>   this case, how should I do that ?

You're onto the right track in the second part, you will need extend the existing one, but not the store, the adapter in this case.

So if you're using ember-cli, which according to this:

> What I have ATM is a newly created project with Ember generator (ember
>   new )

It seems that you are and so you'll application folder structure should be like this:

```
app ->
    adapters(you need to generate/create this)
    components
    controllers
    models
    routes
    serializers
    services
    styles
    templates
```

And now we can answer:

> how should I do that ?

If you do not have the adapters folder yet, which you probably don't, just run `ember generate adapter application` or create a folder adapters, and a file application.js for that folder.

And that then finally leads us to a part of your last question.

> load the ember-data/lib/adapters/elasticsearch_adapter.js file in your
>   application. where and how that should be done ?

```
import ElasticSearchAdapter from 'ember-data/lib/adapters/elasticsearch_adapter'

export default ElasticSearchAdapter.extend({
})
```

Now the possible bad news, that adapter is likely very outdated, as it the repository's last commit was 27 Dec 2012.